# Understanding C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, point-cloud-library

here is the function declaration in my class:

```
template <typename PointInT, typename PointNT, typename PointOutT>
class WrinklednessEstimation: public FeatureFromNormals<PointInT, PointNT, PointOutT>
{
    ...
    void normalsToSpherical(const PointCloud<PointNT> &input, PointCloud<Normal> &output);
    ...
}
```

here is the part of the implementation:

```
template <typename PointInT, typename PointNT, typename PointOutT> void
pcl::WrinklednessEstimation<PointInT, PointNT, PointOutT>::normalsToSpherical(const PointCloud<PointNT> &input, PointCloud<Normal> &output)
{
    ...
}
```

and here is the compiler complaining:

```
wrinkledness.cpp: In member function ‘void pcl::WrinklednessEstimation<PointInT, PointNT, pointOutT>::computeFeature(typename pcl::Feature<PointInT, PointOutT>::PointCloudOut&) [with PointInT = pcl::PointWithViewpoint, PointNT = pcl::Normal, PointOutT = pcl::InterestPoint]’:
wrinkledness.cpp:76:   instantiated from here
wrinkledness.cpp:40: error: no matching function for call to ‘pcl::WrinklednessEstimation<pcl::PointWithViewpoint, pcl::Normal, pcl::InterestPoint>::normalsToSpherical(boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal> >&, boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal> >&)’
wrinkledness.cpp:45: note: candidates are: void pcl::WrinklednessEstimation<PointInT, PointNT, PointOutT>::normalsToSpherical(const pcl::PointCloud<PointOutT>&, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>&) [with PointInT = pcl::PointWithViewpoint, PointNT = pcl::Normal, PointOutT = pcl::InterestPoint]
```

what I do not understand is that why the candidate has `PointOutT` instead of `PointNT` in the first parameter?

Thanks

Comment: Try reading the error message. The compiler written thought it might help you.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `boost::shared_ptr` as arguments when calling the functions. Try calling the function with something like `*my_shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the complaining, but still I don't understand the message.

Comment: @liborw The error doesn't really have anything to do with templates, but it is saying the compiler couldn't find an exactly matching function, but there is a candidate with the same name but different parameters.

Comment: I think the OPs confusion comes from the fact, that he did only define `normalsToSpherical(const PointCloud<PointNT>&, PointCloud<Normal>&);` but the candidate has `normalsToSpherical(const PointCloud<PointOutT>&, PointCloud<Normal>&);`

Comment: Maybe someone can suggest better title?